# How does one prove $\left\lVert\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n\right\rVert\le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\lVert f_n\rVert$?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Can the triangle inequality for norms works for infinite some as well?

Hope that someone can give some hints to prove it or give a counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: If you're working in Banach spaces then you can take advantage of its completeness as does the [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Proof_that_any_absolutely_convergent_series_in_a_Banach_space_is_convergent) of absolute convergence $\implies$ convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Banach function spaces may be a better choice for your question. You can see [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Banach_function_space) for the definition of a Banach function space or this book [Function Spaces, Volume 1](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/174196) (chapter 6).

**Answer to your question:**

The first thing is to introduce the definition of the Riesz-Fischer property.

> We say that  a normed linear space $(X,\left\|\cdot\right\|)$ has the
>   Riesz-Fischer property if for each sequence $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$
>   in $X$ such that  $$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left\|f_n\right\|<\infty, $$
>   there exists an element $f\in X$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f_n=f$
>   in $X$, that is,  $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow
> \infty}\left\|\sum^{n}_{k=1}f_k-f\right\|=0. $$

Since every Banach function space $X$ has the Riesz-Fischer property, we have 
$$
\left\|f\right\|-\sum^n_{k=1}\left\|f_k\right\| \leq \left \|f\right \|-\left \|\sum^{n}_{k=1}f_k \right \| \leq \left \| f - \sum^{n}_{k=1}f_{k} \right\|,
$$
where $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left\|f_n\right\|<\infty$, $f=\sum^\infty_{n=1}f_n$, and $f\in X$.

Then let $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get this result. For a particular example, the Lebesgue space $L^{p}(\Omega)$ is a Banach function space, where $1\leq p \leq \infty$ and $\Omega\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is a suitable domain. As a conclusion, the inequality $\left\|f\right\|\leq\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left\|f_n\right\| $ is still valid in $L^p(\Omega)$.

---

**Supplement:**

The inequality $\left\|f\right\|\leq\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left\|f_n\right\|$ may be invalid if $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left\|f_n\right\|=\infty$ or the normed linear space $(X,\left\|\cdot\right\|)$ doesn't satisfy the Riesz-Fischer property. For the first case, we may not have the conclusion that this series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f_n$ is convergent in $X$. The second is obvious.

Comment: The RF property is nicely put as "every absolutely summable sequence is summable."

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4):

For each $k$, $$\left\lVert\sum_{n=1}^{k}f_n\right\rVert \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{k}\lVert f_n \rVert$$

Then take $k\to\infty$.

Comment: hi~ could you tell me why can I take the limit inside the norm for LHS? Thanks!

Comment: @Nullhoz Use the reverse triangle inequality
$$| \|f\|-\|g\||\le \|f-g\|.$$

Comment: Or, in a wider view, the norm is continuous.